# Get data from vb.net webbrowser dropdown list

Tags: vb.net, dropdown

```
<select name="ddl" id="ddl" class="frmInput2" style="width:160px;">
<option value="-1"> </option>
<option value="11"> Diğer</option>
<option value="4">Amca</option>
<option value="2">Anne</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">Baba</option>
<option value="5">Dayı</option>
<option value="7">Hala</option>
<option value="3">Kardeş</option></select>
```

I want to set the webbrowser dropdown list selected. I was unable to complete the operation, I'm waiting for your help .. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax: `<option value="1" selected>Baba</option>`
[More Info](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

This is an HTML drop-down list, typically, if you are using ASP.NET and you want to retrieve the value server-side, you will want to use an ASP.NET drop-down list.